# Eclipse E4 open Java Editor Programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I would like to know if there is a pure Eclipse E4 way to open programmatically a java editor.

I am migrating my plug-in from Eclipse 3.x to Eclipse E4, and I need to transform the following Eclipse 3.x call into an Eclipse E4 call.

```
final IWorkbenchPage page = Activator.getActiveEditor().getSite().getPage();
IDE.openEditor(page, (IFile) myResource);
```

After search and analysis seem there is not an Eclipse E4 equivalent for this call. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in a pure e4 application.

The Java editor is a 3.x compatibility mode component and won't run in an e4 application. The editor depends on many `org.eclipse.ui.xxx` plugins and things like `IFile` none of which are available in a plain e4 RCP.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the compatibility layer around (which I assume must be the case, as JDT requires it), you should be able to execute the `org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource` command with a `filePath` parameter pointing to your resource. Alas, this command doesn’t give you the guarantee that the Java editor opens – it may just open a plain text editor. But perhaps that’s good enough for you. At least, *your* code doesn’t touch `org.eclipse.ui.*` packages directly (safe for the command’s ID).